# Getting value from array under jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have ended up unexpectedly having to debug some jQuery. Not really my area of expertise. The current scripts are looking for a value inside a textbox that's been rendered by jQuery and failing.

Looking at the DOM in Chrome I can see that the element in question has a "FromDate" element underneath it. The Variables browser lists this as type `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]`. It contains the elements `0: HTMLInputElement, context: HTMLDocument, length: 1` and some other stuff.

The value I'm after is inside the 0 object but I can't seem to find the syntax to get at it. As far as I can tell jQuery constructing things as arrays, but doing `this.FromDate[0]` or `this.FromDate(0)` or `this.FromDate.0 all` yield the error "Property 'FromDate' of object # is not a function".

How do I get my value?

Comment: Could you please post your HTML, and specify which field you are trying to get the value of. It sound like you're looking at the jQuery object in the console, which may be the source of your confusion.

Comment: Could you show the code?

Comment: I have to agree with @RoryMcCrossan; it's highly unlikely that you need to go that deep in jQuery's innards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is a jQuery object.

To access the (first and only) DOM element contained therein, use:

```
myObject[0]
```

or

```
myObject.get(0)
```

If you just want to obtain the value of the `HTMLInputElement` you can use:

```
myObject.val()
```